# When we need to call API from stored procedure OLE method is it secure choice

Tags: sql-server, api, endpoint, ole, ole-automation

I want to get data from endpoint and after process pass back to endpoint and its done by OLE method in SQL. I want to ask question is it secure choice (OLE)? And when should we use it?

I have done it by OLE method in SQL, but I want to ask is it secure or any disadvantages of it

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: i m using **sql-server**,

Comment: Any code can be secure or unsecure - we would need implementation details (code) to be able to give you any help of substance here.